# Center of the universal enveloping algebra

Tags: lie-algebras

Suppose I have non-abelian 2-dimensional Lie algebra or 3-dimensional Heisenberg algebra.

How to calculate the center of universal enveloping algebra in this cases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $U(\mathfrak h)$ be the enveloping Lie algebra of the heisenberg algebra $\mathfrak h$. The algebra $\mathfrak h$ has a basis formeb by
$$X:=
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right),\quad
Y:=
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)\quad
\text{ and }\quad Z:=
\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right).$$
Hence, we have a PBW basis for $U(\mathfrak h)$ given by
$$\{X^aY^bZ^c\colon a,b,c\geqslant 0\}.$$

The relations
$$[X,Y]=Z,\quad [X,Z]=0\quad\text{ and }\quad [Y,Z]=0$$
in $\mathfrak h$ provide the relations
$$YX=XY+Z,\quad ZX=XZ\quad\text{ and }\quad ZY=YZ.$$
Thus, $Z$ is in the center $\operatorname Z(U(\mathfrak h))$ of $U(\mathfrak h)$. We will show above that $Z(U(\mathfrak h))$ is the subalgebra of $U(\mathfrak h)$ generated by $Z$ (i.e. the polynomials in $Z$).

One can prove, by induction in $n\in\mathbb Z_+$, that
$$Y^nX=XY^n + nY^{n-1}Z$$
and
$$YX^n=X^nY + nX^{n-1}Z.$$
The cases where $n=1$ are just the relation $YX=XY+Z$ given above.

With the equations above, one can show that if
$$\alpha = \sum_{i=1}^m\lambda_{a_i,b_i,c_i}X^{a_i}Y^{b_i}Z^{c_i}$$
is not in the subalgebra generated by $Z$ then $\alpha$ is not in $Z(U(\mathfrak h))$ (more specifically, $\alpha$ will not commute with both $X$ and $Y$):

1. Suppose without generality that $(a_i,b_i)\neq (0,0)$ for each $i$.
2. Take
   $$c=\operatorname{max}\{c_1,\dots,c_n\}.$$
3. If
   $$a=\operatorname{max}\{a_i\colon c=c_i,\quad i=1,\dots,n\}>0$$
   and $(a,b,c)=(a_i,b_i,c_i)$ then $\alpha$ does not commute with $Y$ because $Y\alpha$ will have a component in the vector $X^{a-1}Y^bZ^{c+1}$ of the PBW basis and $\alpha Y$ will not.
4. Similarly, if
   $$b=\operatorname{max}\{b_i\colon c=c_i,\quad i=1,\dots,n\}>0$$
   and $(a,b,c)=(a_i,b_i,c_i)$ then $\alpha$ does not commute with $X$ because $\alpha X$ will have a component in the vector $X^aY^{b-1}Z^{c+1}$ of the PBW basis and $X\alpha$ will not.

Therefore, $Z(U(\mathfrak h))$ must be the subalgebra generated by $Z$. Which is, by the way, the subalgebra of $U(\mathfrak g)$ generated by the center of $\mathfrak h$.

The case of the bi-dimensional non-abelian algebra $\mathfrak g$ can be attacked in a similar way. The center of $U(\mathfrak g)$ is the vectorial subspace generated by element $1$. Take a basis formed by $X$ and $Y\in\mathfrak g$ such that $[X,Y]=Y$ in $\mathfrak g$ and consider a PBW basis of $U(\mathfrak g)$ induced by $X$ and $Y$. Then prove that no element in $U(\mathfrak g)\backslash\mathbb K 1$ commute with both $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: @Júlio César I think there is a little ambiguity when you give the PBW basis. It looks as if you considered $X,Y,Z$ as $3\times 3$ matrices as given in the first line and the products $X^a Y^b Z^c$ therein, but the $U(\mathfrak{h})$ is infinite dimensional, not contained in the algebra of $3\times 3$ matrices. (universal algebra = associative algebra "generated" by some elements satisfying some commutation relations, always infinite dimensional)

Comment: @Noix07 I denoted by $X$, $Y$ and $Z$ the mentioned matrices that belong to $\mathbb h$ as well as the image of them by the inclusion $i$ of $\mathbb h$ in $U(\mathbb h)$. As far as I remember, this standard of the Lie algebras books I read. So, I do not get to use  the multiplication of 3x3 matrices as you said to obtain relations between $i(X)$, $i(Y)$, $i(Z)$. But we can use, that $i[X',Y'] = [iX',iY']:= (iX')(iY')-(iY')(iX')$ in $U(\mathcal h)$, for all $X'$, $Y'\in\mathfrak h$ and then obtain the relations I used.

Comment: In no point of the answer we attempt to include $U(\mathfrak h)$ in the algebra of 3x3 matrices. Or at least we shouldn't (my memory might fail), as you observed. Am I less ambiguous? :-)

Comment: Perfect________ I'll delete the comment in a few days

Answer (score 2):

The universal enveloping algebra of the Heisenberg Lie algebra over a field $K$ is generated by $x,y,c$ with relations $xy-yx=c, xc=cx,yc=cy$. Its centre is "almost trivial", equal to the polynomial algebra $K[c]$, if $K$ has characteristic zero.

Edit: Dixmier has computed the center of the universal enveloping algebra for all nilpotent Lie algebras of dimension $n\le 5$, see Proposition $2$ of his article "[Sur les representations unitaires des groupes de Lie nilpotents.III"](https://cms.math.ca/openaccess/cjm/v10/cjm1958v10.0321-0348.pdf), page 326. The elements $f\in Z(U(\mathfrak{h}_1))$ are the elements of the symmetric algebra $S(\mathfrak{h}_1)$ satisfying the equation
$$
[x,y]f'_y+[x,c]f'_c=0,
$$
which implies $f'_x=f'_y=0$, so that $f$ is a polynomial in $c$. From this it follows then $Z(U(\mathfrak{h}_1))=K[c]$.

Comment: But why there are no other elements in center?

Comment: @Alex-omsk: I have edited my answer giving more details.

Comment: So, it is not easy to find this article :(

Comment: I am wondering why f'_x =0 ! And it seems that no Prop. 2 on page 326 is there in the article. Can we see a link of the article plz ?

Comment: @SKH here is the link: [Canadian J. Math.](https://cms.math.ca/10.4153/CJM-1958-033-5). There **is** actually a Proposition $2$ on page 326, as I said. But thank you for pointing out the missing link.